# RDS Blue/Green deployment not working with instances having read replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

I was experimenting with **RDS Blue/Green deployment** , it worked **fine with normal instance** but when I tried with instance **having read replicas in different region** , after clicking on Create Blue/Green deployment it's **just showing loader**

eg . Main instance is on **us-east-1** and it has DB read replica in **eu-central-1** it just showing loader screen on clicking create blue/green deployment

When clicking on create Blue/Green deployment it should show screen with related settings for deployment but it just showing loader

Comment: Please Edit your question to include details of what resources and services you are using. Based on the tags, it seems that you are referring to an Amazon RDS database, but what database engine are you using (eg MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)? Are you referring to [Using Amazon RDS Blue/Green Deployments for database updates - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments.html)? Please add more details to your question. Also, try quitting and restarting your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Blue-Green deployments currently don't support cross-region deployments. If you take a look at the limitations in the documentation below, you can see where they state Cross Region Read Replicas are not supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments-overview.html#blue-green-deployments-limitations

Comment: How should we handle such a case? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Peps - it's not ideal, but this would affect performance rather than up-time, and may create issues with compliance, depending on your business. Deploy replicas in the same region as your master, Delete all read replicas in different regions, then begin B/G update as normal. When complete you can re-create your regional replicas